# How do i change my reolution in Lubuntu? (using xrandr)

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, resolution

I would like help with changing my resolution.

I'm running on Lubuntu (Newest version) and I have no clue how to change my resolution. I know of going to `Menu>Preferences>Monitor` settings but the max is `640x480` and I want to use `1280x1024`.

The options for changing the resolution differs from changing from the Nvidia graphics driver to the Nouveau X.Org driver. So please, can anyone help. It will be much appreciated!

Output of `xrandr`

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        50.0* 
   320x240        51.0  
  1280x1024_60.00 (0x1bb)  109.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock   63.7KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock   59.9Hz
```

Comment: Could you please state your hardware specs.

Comment: AMD 64 Athlon 2.2 ghz processor Nvidia Geforce fx 5200 2gb RAM (System Memory)

Comment: Nvidia Geforce fx 5200 and i have no clue if it is dedicated or integrated.

Comment: What does it show under Menu > Preferences > Additional Drivers?

Comment: Run $ nvidia-xconfig. Then, reboot & delete this file using $ sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf Then, reboot again. This command is experimental.

Comment: nvidia-xconfig was not a recognized command.

Comment: Please reply: What does it show under Menu > Preferences > Additional Drivers?

Comment: It says i am using the proprietary Nvidia legacy  binary driver - version 173.14.39 (recommended driver)

Comment: What does this give you: xrandr|grep ' connected' ?

Comment: It gives me this                                               xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm

Answer (score 0):

First run the command

```
xrandr|grep ' connected'
```

you would see something like

```
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
```

Depending on the above output, you have to note 1.screen name(i.e VGA1 in above ex). Now run the command

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024
```

Replace `VGA1` with  one in your output.

EDIT: For a computer with single screen, the above commands can be replaced by below single command.

```
xrandr --output $(xrandr|grep ' connected'|awk '{print $1}') --mode 1280x1024
```

Comment: I got this.     xrandr|grep ' connected'
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
kyegnosis@kyegnosis-PJ473AA-ABA-M1160N:~$ xrandr --output default --mode 1280x1024
xrandr: cannot find mode 1280x1024
kyegnosis@kyegnosis-PJ473AA-ABA-M1160N:~$

Comment: Also with the new command just posted                              xrandr --output $(xrandr|grep ' connected'|awk '{print $1}') --mode 1280x1024
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find mode 1280x1024

Comment: would you add the output of `xrandr` in your question?

Comment: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        50.0* 
   320x240        51.0  
  1280x1024_60.00 (0x1bb)  109.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock   63.7KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock   59.9Hz

Comment: put that in question,so people may easily find it.

Comment: I edited my questions and posted the xrandr results.

Comment: looks like you have to download and install official driver from nvidia website.

Comment: I have. I am currently using it, though i feel i would have better luck using the X.Org open source diver but if i use that then my Mouse pointer will be invisible.